# Where and how you can place a R-script for its remote work?

Tags: r, remote-server

I have a R script that creates files on the local machine and interacts while working with them. I would like to take the load off the local machine and transfer the script to some remote server. For a while I used "https://www.shinyapps.io/", but it doesn't quite work, since not a shiny application right now. I want to know what are the options for placing my scripts on remote servers, or other ways to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [RStudio Cloud](https://rstudio.cloud/)? The free version would allow you to work on an RStudio Server for a few hours per month. It has most of the features you see on the desktop version.

You won't have access to your local machine but you can upload some files if they're not too large.

Comment: I thinks that this is not quite what i need, since my scripts have to work constantly, and there is an hourly pay